# why remove class not working in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried this before and it worked well but here i dont know...

```
<div onclick="choose(this)">
     <div class="choose">
          <button><a>click</a></button>
     </div>
</div>
```

my JavaScript:

```
function choose(obj) {
  obj = obj || document.activeElement;
  var res_item = obj.querySelector(".choose");
  res_item.classList.add("choosed_item");
  var close = obj.querySelector(".choose button a");
  close.addEventListener("click", function closemodal() {
    if (res_item.classList.contains("choosed_item")) {
      res_item.classList.remove("choosed_item");
    }
  });
}
```

`choose` and `choosed_item` have custom style

This is strange, but if i change `remove` to `add` and choose another class it works well !

Comment: It's because you create an Event on your `close` Element on the first click. Then the next click the child node on the top fires before the parent. The child node is covering the parent anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event is not updated because its child of onclick function. Thats why I integrated an interval. That will help to update the eventlistener:

```
function choose(obj) {
    obj = obj || document.activeElement;
    var interval;
    var res_item = obj.querySelector(".choose");
    res_item.classList.add("choosed_item");
    var close = obj.querySelector(".choose button a");
    close.addEventListener("click", function closemodal() {
      if (res_item.classList.contains("choosed_item")) {
        interval = setInterval(function () {
          res_item.classList.remove("choosed_item");
          stopInterval();
        }, 0);
        function stopInterval() {
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Hope I could help!